# Changing color of CCNodeColor

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I set a CCNode with :

```
CCNodeColor *node = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.1f blue:0.1f alpha:0.0f]];
        node.position=ccp(0,0);
        node.name=@"zoomAlpha";
        [self addChild:node];
```

which works .
than to change its color/alpha :

```
 CCNodeColor *nood=(CCNodeColor*)[self getChildByName:@"zoomAlpha" recursively:NO];
        if(nood)
        {
              //i got here with a nood , but color is not changed
             [nood setColor: [CCColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:1.0f ]];
            return;
        }
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    [nood setColor: [CCColor3B colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:1.0f ]];
```

OR

```
      [nood setColor: [CCColor4B colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:1.0f ]];
```